# RxJava: Is there a cumulative error on long running `intervals`?

Tags: rx-java

I need an observable that emits a "ping" on every full and half minute, i. e. at 9:57:30, 9:58:00, 8:58:30, etc.

It is currently constructed like this:

```
Observable.interval(secondsUntilNextFullOrHalfMinute, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

And the `Subscriber` now has a delay of about 400 ms on each emission and the delays are within 10 ms of each other:

```
onNext: 2015-11-17T09:55:30.409
onNext: 2015-11-17T09:56:00.415
onNext: 2015-11-17T09:56:30.415
onNext: 2015-11-17T09:57:00.415
onNext: 2015-11-17T09:57:30.419
onNext: 2015-11-17T09:58:00.402
onNext: 2015-11-17T09:58:30.410
onNext: 2015-11-17T09:59:00.412
onNext: 2015-11-17T09:59:30.415
onNext: 2015-11-17T10:00:00.417
```

Now I have no problem with the 400ms - I just need to know whether **if I leave the application running for a few days, will there be a cumulative error (by accumulating occasional delays) or will the error remain (more or less) constant**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The periodic timing in RxJava uses a formula to calculate the delay between emissions which somewhat accounts for the time it takes to run the action:

```
long runCount;
long started = ...;

public void call() {
    action.call();

    runCount++;

    long nextAbsolute = started + runCount * delay;

    long nextDelay = nextAbsolute - System.currentTimeMillis();

    worker.schedule(this, nextDelay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

This has the resolution of your system's `currentTimeMillis()` and how accurately your OS can wake up your threads.

This somewhat compensates for drifts but is also the source of recent problems when `currentTimeMillis` is changed drastically: either it takes much longer time to get the next execution or they execute in a quick succession by catching up on all "missed" opportunities.

Comment: So, I guess that means, I can in principle keep doing what I am doing now and hope for the best...